# Automatic printing in C# with ProcessStartInfo cutting off bottom and top

Tags: c#

I am using `ProcessStartInfo` to print my pdf file in my C# project in background. But the file that I printed is cutting off my top and bottom of the pdf file when printed. But when I print the same file by right clicking the pdf file it prints correctly.

Here is my code:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = filename; // use default app to execute verb

         //assert: can only go to local default printer
       startInfo.Verb = "Print"; //prints to default printer                   
        //try to keep Window hidden - work in background
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        // set process to startInfo and execute start
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit(10000);
        process.CloseMainWindow();
        process.Close();
```

Comment: Contact Adobe support for urgent needs, there is no service guarantee here.

Answer (score 1):

this is in milliseconds. so it's only going to wait 10 seconds. Is that long enough?

```
process.WaitForExit(10000);
```

consider

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Is this the solutions for this Mr.madmik3